# How to create Functions for an Online Music Player?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio, audio-player

I have created an Online Music Player for 2 People. 1 Server and 1 Client.
The Server has the Music Files. The client has only the Interface from the Online Music Player. The Server and the Client should use the same Application.
Now, i want the Client to get SQL Data from the Songs into an ListBox / ComboBox like "ID, Name , Writer, Path"
The client then put this data into the SQL Playlist. Where Server and Client can add Songs from the Songs in the Song Data SQL.

**Application**

[[image: Application]

**Playlist SQL**

[[image: SQL]

**Songs SQL**

[[image: SQL2]

**My Goal is that the Client and the Server [IMG 1] can choose from Songs in the ListBox ( SQL Table Songlist [IMG 3]) and put them into the Playlist ( SQL Table Playlist [IMG 2] )**

The problem is that i don't know exactly how to perform this rather difficulty task.
The Song needs to be removed after getting played from the ListBox and the SQL Database.

I don't know how to do this from the SQL Side.

And is my Code clean or could i do something better?

I really hope you can help me out a little bit.

The Code:

```
        private void Button_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string songInfo = LB_Liste.SelectedItem.ToString();
            int startIndex = 2;
            int length = 3;
            string substring = songInfo.Substring(startIndex, length);
            int songId = Convert.ToInt32(substring);
            string songName = lstSongName[songId];
            string songPath = lstSongPfad[songId];

            MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO playlist values(@ID, @Name, @Path, @Que)", MyCon);
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", songId);
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", songName);
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", songPath);
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Que", 0);
            mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            AbrufLeser.Close();
            LB_Playlist.Items.Add(songName);
            UpdateUI();
        }
```

```
        private void Button_Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int playId, playQue;
            string playName = "";
            string playPath = "";

            AbrufKommando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM playlist ORDER BY que", MyCon);
            AbrufLeser = AbrufKommando.ExecuteReader();

            while( AbrufLeser.Read())
            {            
                playId = Convert.ToInt32(AbrufLeser[0]);
                playName = AbrufLeser[1].ToString();
                playPath = AbrufLeser[2].ToString();
                playQue = Convert.ToInt32(AbrufLeser[3]);
            }
                
            Player.URL = playPath;
            TimerR.Start();
            Timer_GIf.Start();
            UpdateUI();
            AbrufLeser.Close();

        }
```

Comment: +Updatet some Vars

Comment: You can create events and sqlDependencry can be used to listen for triggered events. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: Why not just have the list of songs loaded as a List<Songs> in memory and then load the song into your player and play from there? Why do you need a queue table in SQL? You could have a table for PlayLists that allow each listener to arrange the List and the change be reflected in each client?

Answer (score 0):

According to your needs, I wrote a  WinForm Application without using the database. But their logic is the same.

Because you need to perform frequent operations on a set of data, I suggest you use List as a container for storing data.

You could refer to it where I commented on the important places.

Code shows as below

```
List<string> urlList = new List<string>(); //Container for storing playlists
    private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();  //open local directory
            of.Multiselect = true;                      
            of.Title = "Please select a music file";
            of.Filter = "(*.mp3)|*.mp3";
            if (of.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string[] namelist = of.FileNames;       //Save selected song path
                foreach (string url in namelist)        
                {
 
                    listBoxMusics.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(url));   //Display the selected songs in the listbox   
                    urlList.Add(url);        //Store selected songs in previous container
                }
            }
       }
    }
 
    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedIndex = listBoxMusics.SelectedIndex;   //Define an int type to point to the subscript of the listbox
       axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = urlList[selectedIndex];  //The player points to the song stored in the container, that is, plays the selected song in the listbox
    }
 
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)   //The interval of the timer should be adjusted to less than 1000ms
{
 
 
     max = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration;  //duration of a song
 
 
    min = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition;  //The current time a song is playing
 
    trackBar1.Maximum = (int)(max);      //The maximum time of the progress bar
    trackBar1.Value = (int)(min);         //The current time of the progress bar
 
    if (trackBar1.Value == trackBar1.Maximum)
        {
        urlList.RemoveAt(listBoxMusics.SelectedIndex);  //Remove the currently playing song in the container
        listBoxMusics.Items.Clear();      //empty listbox
        foreach (string url in urlList)
        {
            listBoxMusics.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(url));    //Re-add songs in container to listbox
        }
    }
}
```